# Facebook Graph API and friend's email

Tags: apache-flex, facebook

There are some question on the StackOverflow about facebook & email, but after reading them I still have a problem with retrieving users emails.

Our app implemented on Flex and uses REST API. And previously it used notifications.sendEmail.
App has publish_stream and email permissions (checked with users.hasAppPermission).

I tried users.getInfo for get proxied_email address.
But this function does not return email address of the friend..

Then I performed the following test using Graph API and web browser:

1. Opened the following link for authorization with extended permissions:

   > https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[app_id]&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,email&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

It returned code for retrieving access_token

1. Oppened the following link for retrieving access_token

> graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[app_id]&client_secret=[secret]&code=[code]&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

It returned access_token. And now I can use GraphAPI.

1. Tested with my account

> graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[token]

Ok. It returned my emal.

1. Tested with my friend

   > graph.facebook.com/[friend_id]?access_token=[token]

And here is no email field!

So my questions are

Where did I go wrong?
Is it possible to get friend's email via Facebook API (GraphAPI or REST API)?

Thanks.

Comment: you may get more nibbles here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewforum.php?id=52

Comment: I'll ask there too, thx.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Email permission gives access to your email only.

If you look at the [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) page it says:

> Likewise, to protect the privacy of users who have not explicitly authorized your application, your application will only be able to access the basic profile information about a user's friends, like their names and profile pictures. If your application needs to access other data about a user's friends to enable social functionality, you will need to request some of the special friends permissions listed below.

And if you look at the table below, it says "not available" for email permission for  friends.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's clear! There is no way to get friends emails!! f**k!

Comment: Did you find any other way to get friend's email? Even am looking for the same thing. Do we have to ask for any added permission to facebook??

Answer (score 0):

there ought to be some way else how does JanRain does it?
http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/invite-friends

Comment: There is a special Facebook api for inviting friends and Facebook does the emailing.  You don't get the friends emails.

Comment: @BillLeeper What is the name of that api. Can u please provide link to documentation.

Comment: sorry to spout off a solution and not actually provide it.  It was crazy insane to do, and probably doesn't work anymore anyway the way I did it.  I think my method has been removed from the facebook api.

Answer (score 0):

I think that getting friends' email ids is not permitted by Facebook; at least, that's what my research tells me.
@helloworld: Who told you that janrain gets users' friends' email ids?

Answer (score -1):

Only with the **extended permission** you can specify via the **scope attribute**, when obtaining the access token

**Example:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback&
    scope=email
```

Comment: But I already use scope=publish_stream,offline_access,email while https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize

Comment: then you can simply access it at https://graph.facebook.com/username ... if it isnt there it is not available. or the user has not granted, the user can explicitely partly allow your scope or change his/her mail to a proxy email.

Comment: very strange.. I checked my and friend application settings - email access is allowed, so it must show email, right? What additional steps me and friens can do?

Comment: you can only access the email of the user that has authorized the extended permission for your application himself, not his/her friends