# facebook friend finder

Tags: iphone

i am create application in which i want to add facebook friend's email..
is it possible. if possible then how?
please help me.
still now i am not using facebook in any application.

Comment: So you want to add your friend's email to the application?  I don't think I understood the objective of your app.

Comment: @andreas yes man, i want to add facebook's friend's email to send mail or message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible to access to friend's emails.

> Likewise, to protect the privacy of
>   users who have not explicitly
>   authorized your application, your
>   application will only be able to
>   access the basic profile information
>   about a user's friends, like their
>   names and profile pictures. If your
>   application needs to access other data
>   about a user's friends to enable
>   social functionality, you will need to
>   request some of the special friends
>   permissions listed below.

If you look at [this table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), it says "not available" for email field under "Friends permission".

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889463/facebook-graph-api-and-friends-email).

Comment: Thanx,,and  i understand there is no way to get friend's email.