# Retrieve Friends email using Graph API android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Graph API and friend's email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889463/facebook-graph-api-and-friends-email)

I know it is not possible to retrieve friends email addresses but is there any alternative to do it? What i have found out is that a URL like: www.facebook.com/username/info is able to retrieve an HTML page which may or may not contain email addresses. Can we parse through html and then get the data like this?

Answer (score 1):

Scraping isn't really related to Graph API, and while you can do it, this is something no one would recommend (and easily may turn into Platform Policy violation).

BTW, Currently in the source of page there is `email` address of user in url encoded form in an html comment block. (every DOM parser is automatically out of scope), and no one can ensure it will be there. Since changes on Facebook platform are way frequent, this will probably change soon and you'll be in a constant nightmare of figuring what changed and fixing parser...

Actually for communication with your friends via application you should use [social channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) defined by Facebook. You may also be interested in [Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) if you want to send messages to friends.

Comment: I am still stuck at scrapping data from Facebook. This is what i do. 1. the url that im trying to parse is http://m.facebook.com/username?v=info. Then I try to parse the html using jsoup. Everything works fine. but the html data that i recieve is of the login page and not profile page of the user. Even if I have signed the in still i get the html of Login page. PleASe HELP!!